# Using POSIX semaphores between processes (Named semaphores, Linux, C)

Tags: c, linux, posix

The main idea of this simple program is to make communication between processes through the shared memory and limit their access by using semaphores. 'Forks' creating the main Parent Process and 3 Child Processes. Child are consumers and Parent is the producer. Child ought to get in the queue for every information that Parent produces for example: "PP produces word 'thing' -> P1 recives 'thing' -> PP produces next word 'thing2' -> P2 recives 'thing2' -> PP produces next word 'thing3' -> P3 recives 'thing3'" - whole thing goes in circle as long as I like - but its not the problem (I've got the thing working using semaphores from system V).

The problem I encountered is the fact that using 'sem_post' and 'sem_wait' causes segmentation fault (core dumped) - without these program goes (of course it doesn't make much of a sense in that way). I'm not sure if I'm missing something over there, maybe I should open those semaphores inside the child processes (but how?). I'm not a quite expert on that, so I would like to ask somebody for help - maybe its just something simple. :)

If anything needs elaboration I can write something more about it.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char tab[50]; //array for information sending through shared memory
char* buffer; //pointer using to actually send something through shared memory

int main()
{
pid_t P1, P2, P3;
sem_t* mutex_prod;   //sem_t* for producer
sem_t* mutex_kons;   //sem_t* for consumer
key_t pd;            //key for shared memory
int pamID;
char STOP = '.';     //character using to stop input in console

//two semaphores are beeing created - first for producer and second for consumers - both are getting 1 as value (since the main idea is to use binary semaphores)
if ((mutex_prod = sem_open("mutex_prod", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666, 1)) == SEM_FAILED)
{
  perror("Semaphore init");
}
if ((mutex_kons = sem_open("mutex_kons", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666, 1)) == SEM_FAILED)
{
  perror("Semaphore init");
}

pd = ftok("home/mrrobot/Pulpit/memsem/p.c", 5); //some key for shared memory

//creation of shared memory
pamID = shmget(pd, sizeof(char), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
buffer = (char*)shmat(pamID, NULL, 0);
*buffer=0;

if(pamID < 0)
  {
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
  }

memcpy(buffer, tab, 50);

sem_wait(mutex_prod);   //here's problem starting I suppose and continue with every single next sem_wait or sem_post

switch(P1 = fork())
{
    case -1:
    printf("Blad f. fork");
    exit(1);

    case 0:
    while(1)
    {
        sem_post(mutex_kons);        //post for consumer semaphore
        if((char)*buffer == STOP)
            break;
        printf("PK1 (%d) odczytal dane:\n", getpid());
        printf("%s", buffer);
        sem_wait(mutex_prod);   //wait for producer semaphore
    }
    shmdt(buffer);
    exit(0);

    default:
    switch(P2 = fork())
    {
        case -1:
        printf("Blad f. fork");
        exit(1);

        case 0:
        while(1)
        {
            sem_post(mutex_kons);
            if((char)*buffer == STOP)
                break;
            printf("PK2 (%d) odczytal dane:\n", getpid());
            printf("%s", buffer);
            sem_wait(mutex_prod);
        }
        shmdt(buffer);
        exit(0);
    }

    switch(P3 = fork())
    {
        case -1:
        printf("Blad f. fork");
        exit(1);

        case 0:
        while(1)
        {
            sem_post(mutex_kons);
            if((char)*buffer == STOP)
                break;
            printf("PK3 (%d) odczytal dane:\n", getpid());
            printf("%s", buffer);
            sem_wait(mutex_prod);
        }
        shmdt(buffer);
        exit(0);
    }
}
while(1) //main process - producer
{
    sem_post(mutex_prod); //post semaphore of producer
    printf("PP (%d). Podaj dane:\n", getpid());  
    printf("Aby zakonczyc, wcisnij %c i zatwierdz ENTERem\n", STOP); //printf informing about entering new data or ending program by taping '.'

    scanf("%s", &buffer);    //scanf for new data typed in the terminal 
    if((char)*buffer == STOP)
        break;

    //wait for consumers' semaphore
    sem_wait(mutex_kons);
}
//clearing the memory
shmdt(buffer);
shmctl(pamID, IPC_RMID, 0);
sem_unlink("mutex_prod");
sem_unlink("mutex_kons");
sem_close(mutex_prod);
sem_close(mutex_kons);
wait(NULL);
wait(NULL);
wait(NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &buffer);` the `&` shouldn't be here. Is it a typo only here or in the code you are actually running as well?

Comment: It was also in the code - but I tried it previously with and without it - it doesn't cause the actual error. Getting rid of all sem_wait and sem_post makes that the problem does not occur, just after that I'm getting infinite loop with printing everything all over the terminal - because semaphores don't block anything as they should.

Comment: Also not likely related: the check `if(pamID < 0)` should be before `shmat()`. Also you should check the return value of `shmat()` itself.

Comment: Okey, I'm getting the idea. The program sort of worked after I reboot'ed it - the problem with its memory comes after I already created some semaphores but I didn't clear em up properly - because of the problems - I had to turn it off in the terminal using "CTRL+Z" combination for example. The problem persist as long as they are semaphores in the system - so how could I get rid off them after failure of program (by failure I mean that I had to terminate it in an unusual way - like "CTRL+Z" methoded as I mentionet)? Shmat() works just fine as I checked.

Comment: Remove them from `/dev/shm`.

Comment: Yeah, that helped. Thank you very much - now everything is fine and program itself works as I wanted it to be (With a minor change in the way of reading input into shared memory). Anyway the main problem is gone. :D